# Rails 3 custom validator 'stomps' existing validations

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple CRUD app with some basic validations for a Commodity model. The tests for those pass. OK, now I need to test against having no spaces, or more than one word for its name. I tested the below in console and it seemed to work so reading up on the rails guides on validations I wrote a custom validation below. Unfortunately running my tests, all fail now because it cannot create a commodity because it fails due to the custom validation I wrote. I've tried many different combinations of incorprating the validator starting with Railscasts #211 by combining it into the validates call. It's probably something simple but if I yank out the call to the validator then the other basic tests pass. The error is: Validation failed: Name must be a single word (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

```
 require_relative 'commodity_name_validator'
 class Commodity < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :description, :name
   has_many :prices
   before_save { |commodity| commodity.name.capitalize! }
   validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
   validate :commodity_name_validations
 end

 class CommodityNameValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
   def validate(record)
     if record.name.split(" ").length <= 1
       record.errors[:base] << "Name must be a single word"
     end
   end
 end
```

thnx, sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this 'stomp' is due to cucumber throwing errors earlier when it encounters a basic error in this case. Thanks to @jorendorff pointing out that replacing my <= 1 to != 1 made this test pass and those previous to pass as well. I don't know if it's ruby's reflection or what that causes previous passing tests to error out, I'm speaking out of ignorance. I just know that cucumber, at least, will throw errors that mislead to the real cause.